# Why kotlin script file cannot have inherited class in the same file?

Tags: class, inheritance, kotlin, compilation, final

I'm wring my.kts script, and use it to run kotlin, I've got this:

```
class TestA {
    init {}
    open fun testOpen() {
        println(this)
    }
}
class TestB : TestA {
    override fun testOpen() {
        super.testOpen()
    }
}
```

It fails to compile, saying that:

```
error: this type is final, so it cannot be inherited from
class TestB : TestA {
          ^
basic.kts:39:15: error: this type has a constructor, and thus must be     initialized here
```

class TestB : TestA {

Comment: follow this example: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inherit one class from another and base class has primary constructor, it must be initialised. Your `TestA` has default primary constructor, so it should look like:

```
class TestB : TestA() {
    override fun testOpen() {
        super.testOpen()
    }
}
```

Another problem is that classes in kotlin are final by default and you should explicitly define that they can be extended:

```
open class TestA
```

Check [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance) examples for more information.